# AlpineJS and $nextTick count list items after filter

Tags: alpine.js

I have a filterable list which gets rendered in PHP. So I don't handle the rendering with a JSON and AlpineJS templates.

The List gets filtered via two select inputs. This works as inteded. But I can't make the counter work, which counts all the visible list items, after updating the list.

As soon as I use "$nextTick(()", I get a syntax error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at new AsyncFunction"

When I omit "$nextTick(() => " it works, but the counter is always one step behind.

The strange thing is, in codepen it works. So I guess the sequence of enqueuing the AlpineJS script is wrong. But even if i load it in the footer, I have the same issue. Any ideas?

```
<div x-data="alpine.filter()">

    <select id="ort" name="ort" x-model="ort" @change="$nextTick(() => updateResultsCount());">
        <option value=" "="">Alle Orte                  
        <option value="bregenz">Bregenz</option>
        <option value="frastanz">Frastanz</option>                  
    </select>
    
    <select id="kategorie" name="kategorie" x-model="kategorie" @change="$nextTick(() => updateResultsCount());">
        <option value="">Alle Kategorien</option>
        <option value="kategorie-a">Kategorie A</option>
        <option value="uncategorized">Uncategorized</option>                    
    </select>

<div><span x-text="currentCount"></span> entries</div>
    
<div class="toggle" x-show="(!ort || ort === 'bregenz') &amp;&amp; (!kategorie || kategorie === 'kategorie-a')" x-data="{ open: false, switchOpen: function() { this.open = !this.open } }" x-bind:class="{ 'active': open }" data-ort="bregenz" data-kategorie="kategorie-a" style="display: none;">Toogle Content</div>

<div class="toggle" x-show="(!ort || ort === 'frastanz') &amp;&amp; (!kategorie || kategorie === 'kategorie-a')" x-data="{ open: false, switchOpen: function() { this.open = !this.open } }" x-bind:class="{ 'active': open }" data-ort="frastanz" data-kategorie="kategorie-a">Toogle Content</div>


<script>
window.alpine = {};
    window.alpine.filter = function() {
        return {
            ort:'',
            kategorie:'',   
            currentCount: '#php_variable#',
            items: [...document.querySelectorAll('.toggle')],
            filteredItems: 0,
            updateResultsCount: function() { //das wird zu früh ausgeführt
                this.currentCount = [...document.querySelectorAll('.toggle')].filter(toggle => window.getComputedStyle(toggle).display !== 'none').length;
                console.log(this.currentCount);
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx/vendor/alpine.js" id="alpinejs-js"></script>
```

Codepen with the code:
https://codepen.io/flore89/pen/YzOrvmR

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that if I use a "classical" function instead of an arrow function, it works.

```
@change="$nextTick(() => updateResultsCount());"
to this
@change="$nextTick( function() { updateResultsCount() } )"
```

I have no idea why, because in the codepen the arrow function works..